# How to receive additional parameters in jquery success method ()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm validating my html form with `Jquery/Ajax` Call. It's process by Php. In php page its return all success result or error result after processing To Jquery Success method.

SO I want to receive another parameters in jquery success method (). Is there any way to received it ?

**for example :** in this following line code If `$numSearch` is == 0

```
elseif($numSearch === 0){
    echo "<font color='red'>No Matches.</font>";
}
```

then I want to received another parameters in jquery success method so that I can load `getDetails2(SearchValue);` function. Now it's load when the value is `integer`. But it's should be check if value is Integer and result is showing something.

**Php code :**

```
require_once("corefile.php");
$search = (int) $_POST['data'];
$cdid = inputvalid($_POST['cdid']);

if($cdid == "ID"){
    // if serach value is empty 
    if(empty($search)){
        echo "<font color='red'>Search keyword required.</font>";
    }
    // if serach value is not empty
    elseif(!empty($search)){        
        // start myqli_query to search
        //$numserach
    }
    elseif($numSearch === 0){
        echo "<font color='red'>No Matches.</font>";
    }
}
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#cdid").click(function() {                
        var SearchValue = $('#txt_name').val();
        var cdid = $('#cdid').val();         

        $("#loading-image").show();         
        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST",
            url: "doSearch.php",             
            data :  {
            'data' : SearchValue,
            'cdid' : cdid
        },          

        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
        if(Math.floor(SearchValue) == SearchValue && $.isNumeric(SearchValue)){
            getDetails2(SearchValue);           
        } 

        $("#showSearchResult").html(response);                  
        $('#visiableaftersearch').hide();
        document.getElementById('txt_name').value='';
        document.getElementById('txt_given_name').value='';
        $("#loading-image").hide();

        }           
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done, Use `dataType: "json"` in Ajax call(instead of  HTML response), and send some flags for error & Success , based on that flags parse your `Json` response.

For eg,

The php file you are making an ajax request , should encode returning data in Json format, like(with the necessary flags)

```
//example 
echo json_encode(array($con_info));
```

Comment: Yes I know it's can be done Using `dataType : "jsone"`. But It can't be done using `dataType : "html"` ?

Comment: parsing and sending AJAX data in json is much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if you use JSON, so you can add more value as key value pair, in JSONObject such as:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Then using JSON.parse, parse the data from success method. Then loop it, to get the key & value separately.

```
success: function(response){   
   var json=JSON.parse(response);

   jQuery.each(json, function(i, val) {
        console.log("key : "+i+" value: "+val);
    });
}
```